# Как подключить JS библиотеку к Chrome Exxtensions ?

Tags: jquery, javascript, chrome-extension

Пытаюсь подключить jQuery или Mousetrap.

```
Сам файл манифеста:

{
  "name": "CHANGE THIS",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This extension was created with the awesome extensionizr.io",
  "homepage_url": "http://extensionizr.com",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://vk.com/*"],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js",
        "src/jqury.min.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

И вызываю из inject.js

```
$('#side_bar').append('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
```

В консоле пишется, что

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Как быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подключать jQuery надо ДО inject.js:

```
  "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://vk.com/*"],
  "js": [
    "src/jqury.min.js",
    "src/inject/inject.js"
  ]
```